VScode wsl,exe Unable to start debugging,
Unable to start debugging, There was an error starting the pipe program C:\Windows\System32\wsl,exe. An error occurred trying to start process C:Windows\System32\wsl.exe with working directory '/mnt/c/wsl shared/CodeV3' No such file or directory
my launch.json

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "WSL: Launch CTCInterface",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/mnt/c/wsl_shared/CodeV3/build/CTCInterface",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "/mnt/c/wsl_shared/CodeV3",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "CMake: build",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeCwd": "/mnt/c/wsl_shared/CodeV3",
                "pipeProgram": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
                "pipeArgs": [],
                "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/mnt/c": "C:\\"
            }
        }
    ]
}


Begin from trying to find out cause of this - No such file or directory my launch.json.

Try : "pipeCwd": "c:/wsl_shared/CodeV3"
